# Is it possible to access visual studio build event settings in code? [C#]

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am looking for building a unit test case to validate whether build event value specified under a class library or not?

So is it possible to access the values specified under Class Library > Properties > Build Events > Pre and Post Build Events?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you unload the project file, and you right click and click on Edit, you will have a new PropertyGroup with a node to the PreBuildEvent / PostBuildEvent.

However, I am not sure if you can do that programatically. But you probably can via MSBuild.
-> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/propertygroup-element-msbuild?view=vs-2017